# Running multiple cmds using bat file?

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I have been trying to run multiple cmds to execute the same command with different arguments but cmd does not work. Here is the code to run the file

```
cd\
cd F:\A 5th Semester Data\CN\Project\
start cmd \k python test.py A 5000 configA.txt
```

The next statements will have B, 5001 configB.txt and so on.
Please Help in this matter.
Best Regards.

Comment: can't you do this inside Python script ? it will be easier to use python to increase values.

Comment: The task requirement is that we give it its arguments in cmd. But we have to run it multiple times and I can't figure out how.

Comment: batch has own function `for` so you could try to use it. Or you can write Python script which will execute `python test.py` many times with different arguments.

Comment: Do not forget the `/D` switch of the [`cd` command](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)!

Comment: How high do the letters and numbers go? I see A-5000 and B-5001, so I assume there will be C-5002, but will there be A-5001, A-5002, etc.?

Comment: numbers go till F-5005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File and folder paths containing a space character must be enclosed in double quotes as explained in last paragraph of last help page output by running in a command prompt window `cmd /?`.

The help explains also parameter `/K` as used by you to keep the console window open after Windows command interpreter finished execution of `python` which means after Python finished execution of `test.py`.

And command **CD** requires the usage of parameter `/D` if the drive should be also switched as explained in help output by running in a command prompt window `cd /?`.

```
cd /D "F:\A 5th Semester Data\CN\Project"
start cmd /k python test.py A 5000 configA.txt
```

The help of command **START** is output on running in a command prompt window `start /?` which lists and explains also the parameter `/Dpath`.

So the two lines above could be also written as one-liner:

```
start "Python Processing" /D"F:\A 5th Semester Data\CN\Project" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /K python.exe test.py A 5000 configA.txt
```

But it looks like what you really need is a batch file containing the lines:

```
cd /D "F:\A 5th Semester Data\CN\Project"
python.exe test.py A 5000 configA.txt
python.exe test.py B 5001 configB.txt
rem and so on
```

Or using a **FOR** loop and an environment variable with delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /D "F:\A 5th Semester Data\CN\Project"
set "Number=5000"
for %%I in (A B C D E) do (
    python.exe test.py %%I !Number! config%%I.txt
    set /A Number+=1
)
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`